# How can I update item of recyclerview from dialogfragment?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my app I get some data from server in json. Then I fetch fields from json and fill my RecyclerView list with custom adapter. This list is filled with data about jobs. When I click on a job of my recyclerView I move from hosting fragment to dialogfragment for viewing it. This dialogFragment contains homesUp button after pressing which I return to hosting activity. At this dialogFragment I have button which send request to server about this job for adding it to another DB at server. 
But when I press this button and send request to the server then after returning to hosting activity I see that data of selected isn't changed. I have several ways of solving this problem:

1. Add to my Singleton class variable of ArrayList which will be filled by data of shown job and then I will check whether my Arraylist from Singleton contains this id
2. another method - notifyItemChanged()

All these methods don't work because my list is filled by old data and I only dismiss dialogFragment and return to fragment which contains the list with old data.

> Only one way - send request to server for filling the list again.

So, I need your help or useful advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to broadcast changed data  from dialog fragment to previous screen. For doing this can use LocalBroadcastManager or rxjava or  even live data.

Or create a pagedlistadapter from paging library released in android architecture complement and load data directly from query. 
Reference: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging

Comment: so I will be able to change data of RV after clicking button at dialogFragment?

Comment: how I can add for example local broadcast manager at adapter class for RV?

Comment: Yeah if using pagedlistadapter u need to change your data in your local database and change would automatically be reflected in recyclerview

Comment: I don't have local db, I have variable at activity of arraylist and it is all :( and for adding pagedlistadapter I have to remake my adapter?

Comment: Do u know rxjava?

Comment: little bit :( I heard about it, but I have never used it before I think or not, how it will help me in my problem?

Comment: U can create a behaviour subject and publish updates from you dialog fragment to your recyclerview screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194426/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and-abhijeet-kumar).

Comment: Actually an interface will solve this problem right?

Comment: @RameesThattarath That too is possible and much easier approach.